# How do I localize an assignment to expression (instead of symbol) within scoping construct?

Tags: function-construction, scoping

Is it possible to localize an assignment to an expression (defined via `UpSet`) instead of a `Symbol` within a scoping construct?

It would be nice if I had something like the following at my disposal:

```
Block[{f[1,2]=ab}, (*<-- what I need*)
  Table[f[i,j],{i,1,2},{j,1,2}]
]
```

(I need to use `Block`.  `Module` and `With` are not correct for my case.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need to preserve the definitions of a `Symbol` with exception(s) to some particular case(s) you should use [`` Internal`InheritedBlock ``](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5686710/590388):

```
f[a_, b_] := a + b;

Internal`InheritedBlock[{f}, f[1, 2] := ab;
 Table[f[i, j], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]]

f[1, 2]
```

> ```
> {{2, ab}, {3, 4}}
>
> 3
> ```

Comment: This is even better than my answer!  Thanks

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71881/what-is-the-purpose-of-internallocalizedblock/71883?noredirect=1#comment197070_71883