# What is the purpose of Internal`LocalizedBlock?

Tags: scoping, undocumented

I have come across the (internal) use of the function:

```
Internal`LocalizedBlock
```

I am trying to determine its purpose.  It seem to behave like [`` Internal`InheritedBlock ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25769/121) except that a starting value (e.g. `{x = 3}`) cannot be set.

```
x = "global"; f[] := x

Internal`LocalizedBlock[{x}, {x, x = 7, f[], Hold[x]}]
x

Internal`InheritedBlock[{x}, {x, x = 7, f[], Hold[x]}]
x
```

> ```
> {"global", 7, 7, Hold[x]}
>
> "global"
>
> {"global", 7, 7, Hold[x]}
>
> "global"
> ```

What purpose does this function serve?  Why would it be used in place of `InheritedBlock`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`` Internal`LocalizedBlock `` behaves the same as `Block`, but it can localize non-Symbols (e.g. `f[1]`, `Subscript[x, 0]`, etc.).

For example,

```
Internal`LocalizedBlock[{Subscript[x, 0]}, Subscript[x, 0] = 1]
(* 1 *)
```

Compare this to

```
Block[{Subscript[x, 0]}, Subscript[x, 0] = 1]
(* During evaluation of In[79]:= Block::lvsym: Local variable specification {Subscript[x, 0]} contains Subscript[x, 0], which is not a symbol or an assignment to a symbol. >> *)
(* Block[{Subscript[x, 0]}, Subscript[x, 0] = 1] *)
```

It's also worth noting that one cannot assign values in the first argument of `` Internal`LocalizedBlock ``

Comment: So would ``Internal`LocalizedBlock`` be an answer to this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64673/how-do-i-localize-an-assignment-to-expression-instead-of-symbol-within-scoping

Comment: @QuantumDot It seems so.  Perhaps you wish to self-answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  I guess I'm not familiar enough with ``Inherited`LocalizedBlock`` to provide a confident answer.  Maybe I'll add it in the comments section.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard just a little tidbit, if I recall correctly this was added for the purpose of fitted models being able to work with subscripted variables so I think Dan is right on here.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 12):

**Disclaimer:** these are all guesses, believe at your own risk.

As the first argument, you specify a list of patterns to localize. For example, `{x}`, `{x[2]}`, `{x[][2]}`, or `x[2]/;True`

This creates a dynamic environment around the second argument inside which the following happens:

- Changes to those patterns' own/down/subvalues while in the environment aren't kept after its execution.
- If the pattern is

  - *a symbol (e.g `x`, `f`)*:

    works like block, and all of the symbol's definitions don't apply inside the localized block
  - *a non-pattern pattern that doesn't have a downvalue/subvalue outside the environment:* (by non-pattern pattern I just mean a pattern that don't have conditions, pattern tests, blanks, etc. such as `x[2]]` or `x[][5]`. I wonder if there's a standard name in the community for these)

    does nothing
  - *any other pattern `patt`:*

    Temporarily set the definition `` patt:=System`Private`$Localized ``. This is a definition that makes the whole downvalue/subvalue lookup fail to find a match. [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9679/109) is a usage example;

*Low importance note:* this changes seem to be applied in order of appearance, so if the first argument is `{x, x[2]/;True}`, then the definition `x[2]/;True:=System`Private`$Localized` will be added, while it won't be with the order reversed to `x[2]/;True, x}`

**Summary**

You can use it to

- Change specific down/sub/ownvalues of a symbol while in a dynamic environment without it affecting the outside, but allowing all other definitions changes to leak.
- Work with the outside definitions of the symbol but making some particular pattern behave as undefined.

Comment: Is this how you propose ``Internal`LocalizedBlock`` works or simply an idea you wish to implement some time?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard how I think it works. Does it fail easy tests?

Comment: No, I just wasn't sure of your intent. :-)

Comment: Ok, I now can test this. Let's see

Comment: [believe it or not](http://rlv.zcache.com/the_x_files_i_want_to_believe_poster_flying_pig-r378f84dc05d345bba95966acfb1ac3c4_ixfhx_8byvr_512.jpg?bg=0xffffff)